# Laravel model object chaining

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

For some reason, I cannot chain model objects.  I'm trying to eager load 'Location' for an 'Order' and would prefer the logic to be contained in the models themselves.  But past one chain, it does not work.

```js
class Order extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'orders';

    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer');

    public function location() {
        return $this->customer()->location(); // this does not work
    }
}

class Customer extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'customers';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }

    public function location() {
        return $this->user()->location();
            // return $this->user(); // WORKS!!
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function locations() {
        return $this->hasMany('Location');
    }

    public function location() {
        return $this->locations()->first();
    }
}
```

I eventually want to do this:

```js
class ChefController extends BaseController {
    public function get_orders() {
        $chef = $this->get_user_chef(); // this already works
        return $chef->orders()->with('location')->get(); // does not work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference relation (user table) by adding user_id as second argument, like this:

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User',"user_id");
}
```

Maybe you called that **id** field different, but you know what I mean.

Comment: Isn't this the default?

Comment: Well, when you name your method other then model name, you have to be explicit about id.

Comment: The method name is different to the model?

Comment: you can call your method owner for example, and provide correct id of original method that belongsTo.